# Decrypting a string in C# that was encoded in GO using the AES-GSM method

Tags: c#, go, cryptography, aes, aes-gcm

I've got a string that was AES-GCM encrypted in Go, along with it's pass phrase and am trying to decrypt it in C#. However, I'm unable to find the right methods to decrypt the same in C#.
The errors I'm getting mentions the size of the IV, block not being the right lengths for the C# decryption algorithm. Below are the values from Go:

> AES encr/decr Passphrase:  this-is-a-test-passphrase

> Input String:  text to encrypt hello world 123

> Encrypted String:  94b681ef29d9a6d7-e6fa36c4c00977de1745fc63-a1ad0481bdbeeaa02c013a2dce82520ddd762355e18f1e2f20c0ea9d001ece24e9b8216ed4b9c6a06e1ef34c953f80

GO code: https://go.dev/play/p/jN8Ie61Ntzw

This is the decryption code in Go

```
func AppDecryptImpl(passphrase, ciphertext string) string {
arr := strings.Split(ciphertext, "-")
salt, _ := hex.DecodeString(arr[0])
iv, _ := hex.DecodeString(arr[1])
data, _ := hex.DecodeString(arr[2])
key, _ := appDeriveKey(passphrase, salt)
b, _ := aes.NewCipher(key)
aesgcm, _ := cipher.NewGCM(b)
data, _ = aesgcm.Open(nil, iv, data, nil)
return string(data)
}

func appDeriveKey(passphrase string, salt []byte) ([]byte, []byte) {
if salt == nil {
    salt = make([]byte, 8)
    rand.Read(salt)
}
return pbkdf2.Key([]byte(passphrase), salt, 1000, 32, sha256.New), salt
}
```

And this is the encryption code in Go

```
func AppEncryptImpl(passphrase string, plaintext string) string {
key, salt := appDeriveKey(passphrase, nil)
iv := make([]byte, 12)
rand.Read(iv)
b, _ := aes.NewCipher(key)
aesgcm, _ := cipher.NewGCM(b)
data := aesgcm.Seal(nil, iv, []byte(plaintext), nil)
return hex.EncodeToString(salt) + "-" + hex.EncodeToString(iv) + "-" + hex.EncodeToString(data)
}
```

I'm trying to replicate the same decryption login in C#, so it'll be able to decrypt and produce the final string.

I've tried several logic when it comes to decryption in C#, they can be found here:

- https://dotnetfiddle.net/32sb5m This one uses the System.Security.Cryptography namespace, but it results in an IV size error.
- https://dotnetfiddle.net/WxKUYR A modified version of the above for .NET 5 produces the same result
- https://dotnetfiddle.net/6IfTps Using the bouncy castle library results in an "mac check in GCM failed" error
- https://dotnetfiddle.net/8mJS3G Another method using the Rfc2898DeriveBytes method produces an error saying "The computed authentication tag did not match the input authentication tag"

Is the approach that's currently being used the right approach or is there another method to decrypt AES-GCM it in C#? And what can be done to bypass these errors when it comes to C#?

Comment: First & second uses CBC, third uses wrong nonce / IV size, last one forgets to subtract the tag from the ciphertext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close with the last code. Go appends authentication tag to the end of produced ciphertext. And you correctly extract it here:

```
// Extract the tag from the encrypted byte array
byte[] tag = new byte[16];
Array.Copy(encryptedData, encryptedData.Length - 16, tag, 0, 16);
```

But then you continue to treat array with actual encrypted text + auth tag as if it contained only encrypted text. To fix, extract it also:

```
public static void Main() {
    // This is the encrypted string that you provided
    string encryptedString = "a6c0952b78967559-2953e738b9b005028bf4f6c0-7b8464d1ed75bc38b4503f6c8d25d6bfc22a19cc1a8a92bc6faa1ed6cd837b97072bc8e16fd95b6cfca67fccbad8fc";

    // This is the passphrase that you provided
    string passphrase = "this-is-a-test-passphrase";

    string[] splitStrs = encryptedString.Split('-');

    byte[] salt = Convert.FromHexString(splitStrs[0]);
    byte[] iv = Convert.FromHexString(splitStrs[1]);
    // this is encrypted data + tag
    byte[] encryptedDataWithTag = Convert.FromHexString(splitStrs[2]);
    // Extract the tag from the encrypted byte array
    byte[] tag = new byte[16];
    // But also extract actual encrypted data
    byte[] encryptedData = new byte[encryptedDataWithTag.Length - 16];
    Array.Copy(encryptedDataWithTag, 0, encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
    Array.Copy(encryptedDataWithTag, encryptedDataWithTag.Length - 16, tag, 0, 16);
    byte[] key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passphrase, salt, 1000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256).GetBytes(32);
    // Create an AesGcm object
    AesGcm aesGcm = new AesGcm(key);
    int textLength = encryptedData.Length;
    // Decrypt the ciphertext
    byte[] plaintext = new byte[textLength];
    aesGcm.Decrypt(iv, encryptedData, tag, plaintext);
    // Convert the plaintext to a string and print it
    string decryptedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plaintext);
    Console.WriteLine(decryptedString);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This had me scratching my head for a long time. I was also able to convert your code to work with .NET 4 using bouncy castle instead of AesGcm.